# Custom Validation not firing, build-in does

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I cant get my Custom Validator to fire in ASP.NET Core MVC.

I try to use a validator to check if the domain of the input e-mail is known

```
public class AllowedDomain : ValidationAttribute
{
    public AllowedDomain() : base()
    {
    }

    public string GetErrorMessage() => $"Some Error Message";

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        AllowedDomainRepository repo = (AllowedDomainRepository)validationContext
                     .GetService(typeof(AllowedDomainRepository));

        string domain = value as string;

        if (repo.hasDomain(domain))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else 
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And I use it like this in my `RegisterModel`:

```
[BindProperty]
public InputModel Input { get; set; }

....

public class InputModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [AllowedDomain]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    ....
}
```

but somehow the `[EmailAdress]` attribute is working, as is the `[Required]` but I can't even get mine to fire (it's not reaching a breakpoint in the `isValid` method) even though `Required` and mine both inherit from `ValidationAttribute`.

EDIT: I got it to fire, once I post, but this is too late.

`[EmailAdress]` does fire while the input field looses focus which is what I want for my validation, too.

Comment: How controller method looks like where you use your `RegisterModel`? And by the way, I gave your attribute a try and it works just fine. Something else must be standing in the way.

Comment: @Prolog Its the default Scaffold generated by Visual Studio for the Register Page of an MVC Projekt with identity. So there is no seperated controller, only the RegisterModel  File with its Tasks OnPostAsync & OnGetAsync

Comment: Short answer; `[EmailAddress]` is translated to client side javascript, `[AllowedDomain]` is not. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51694431/how-to-do-client-side-validation-in-custom-validation-attribute-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Ok, thank you. I'll check it out